# Bezier curve produces sharp angles on extrusion

Tags: shaders, bezier-curves

I'm trying to create a 3D model of an awareness ribbon (shown in images on the right). To do it I'm using a bezier curve, which I then extrude to 0.1m and apply tilt angles at certain points of the curve.

On the attached photo with the bezier curve outline it is seen the curve is smooth and has no sharp edges. However, when I extrude it a sharp edge appears at the top of the ribbon (highlighted with arrows).

I also can't manage to twist ant tilt the ribbon like in the reference image. What am I doing wrong and is there any way I can solve this issue?

[image: Screenshot with the bezier curve extruded]

[image: Screenshot with the bezier curve in editing mode and not extruded]

Comment: I think you'll be happier if you set the tilt interpolation (properties/data/active spline) to "cardinal".

Comment: That worked indeed! Now I just need to figure out why the tilt displays the width at the fold as 0

Comment: The width-- as in, the length of the edge-- is exactly the same at your sharp edge as it is anywhere else.  It is, in part, an artifact of the view and of how the curve is divided into segments.